# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I'm using Oracle in Windows server and I have been granted the DBA role and now I'm trying to unlock a user account using:

```
ALTER USER user_account ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

and I get this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
```

and I don't know why! knowing that DBA role can alter user!

so, what maybe is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

`DBA` - by default - has privilege to alter other users. How do I know?

```
SQL> select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'DBA' order by privilege;

GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE                                ADM
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ---
DBA                            ADMINISTER ANY SQL TUNING SET            YES
DBA                            ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER              YES
DBA                            ADMINISTER RESOURCE MANAGER              YES
<snip>
DBA                            ALTER USER                               YES    --> this
DBA                            ANALYZE ANY                              YES
DBA                            ANALYZE ANY DICTIONARY                   YES
<snip>
```

Therefore, either your user isn't granted the `DBA` role, or someone removed `ALTER USER` from it.

Comment: when i execute `select * from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'DBA'` my user shows in the output and granted DBA

Comment: I'm guessing the role isn't default for the session

Comment: i executed `SET ROLE ALL; ` and all roles are set but still get the same error